# Image corruption while saving pictures on Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I'm trying to create an app to take photos the problem is when I try to save the picture at a internal folder of the app. Some pictures are good and other are corrupted like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M81x.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/McIa4.jpg

The first have an error / Second is okay

And this is my code that I'm using :

```
   class CameraPictureCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Camera.IPictureCallback
{
    const string APP_NAME = "CameraApp";
    Context _context;

    public CameraPictureCallback(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures) + "/XFRecognition";
        try
        {
            Toast.MakeText(_context, "test click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            string fileName = "test.jpg";

            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }
            using (var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir,fileName)))
            {
                 fileOutputStream.Write(data);
            }

            camera.StartPreview();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug(APP_NAME, "File not found: " + e.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas for the problem?

Comment: Did you get some error message ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT actually im not getting errors, but some pictures are saved corrupted. The strange part is if i search manually in the folder where the pictures are saved and change the name of the corrupted picture to other name for some reason the picture are okay i mean it looks normal like the other ones without black screen or rectangles in the half of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin **Xam.Plugin.Media** from nuget .Which can  take photos and video or pick them from a gallery .

```
   private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            //"No Camera Available"
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,
        //Directory = "Sample",
        //Name = "Test.jpg"
    });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        var imgDate = GetImageStreamAsBytes(file.GetStream());


        // save it to folder
    }
```

And convert it to byte array

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

For more details about the plugin you could check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin